# How can I get report from work item (bug) transition between states diagram of bug in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, report

A State Diagram of Bug consists of 3 states. I am going to calculate the ratio of s1 to s2, `R=s1/s2`, in TFS 2010.

- S1 is the number of times that a special bug transfers from `Resolved` state to `Active` state.
- S2 is the number of times that a developer transfers that special bug from `Active` state to `Resolved` state.

[image: The Diagram].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take:

You have two ways to build a report:

1. Using SQL Reporting Services, in this case such report doesn't exist so you'll have to develop your own. If you're familiar with SSRS then go for it if you have some time to spend, otherwise, it's pretty hard to get what you want.
2. Using Excel to address the TFS OLAP Cube, you'll find there the data you need. Then you can generate an Excel Graph, save the Excel file and refresh the content each time you want.

I think you should try the second solution, you'll find all the information you need [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244710.aspx) and [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244678)